# Unable to get an object in gstreamer application using g_value_set_object() from gstreamer plugin

Tags: gstreamer

I have a gstreamer test application. My intention is to get a structure defined in one of my gstreamer plugin to my application. But I am getting segmentation fault.

Test Application snippet :

```
notify_func(GObject *obj)
{
  GObject *myobj;
  g_object_get(obj, "my-prop", &myobj,NULL);  
}
```

Plugin Snippet:

```
get_property()
{
  case MY_PROP:
  g_value_set_object(value, obj1->myStructure);
  break;
}
```

Structure :

```
struct obj1 {
  MyStructure *myStructure;
  ...
};
```

But I am getting segmentation fault from g_value_set_object. To be exact G_IS_OBJECT(obj) crashed. my obj1 instance is of type GST_TYPE_ELEMENT. Could any one suggest what is happening ?

Comment: First of all, the code you provide is much less than anyone might need to actually help you. 
But I'll try it anyway: the issue seems to be that the parameter `value` in `g_value_set_object` is not a `GObject` (or `GstElement` or one of the other extending structures). Make sure you've correctly initialized it using `gst_element_factory_make()` or the like.

Comment: Please also show your definition for the MY_PROP property (for _class_init).

Answer (score 1):

I had written similar kind of "sample" Gstreamer plugin and Gstreamer application to test the plugin. Hope it helps and also answers your question :)

Gstreamer plugin code:-

**Header File:**

```
typedef struct _test
{
    gchar *filename;
    guint width;
    guint height;
}TEST;

struct _GstSample 
{
    GstElement element;
    GstPad *src;
    GstPad *sink;
#ifndef STRUCTURE   
    gchar *filename;
    guint width;
    guint height;
#else
    TEST *test;
#endif  
    gboolean test_arg;
};
```

**C File**

```
gst_sample_class_init(GstSampleClass *klass)
{
  ....
  g_object_class_install_property(gobject_class, PROP_TEST,
    g_param_spec_pointer("test", "test", "Structure Testing", G_PARAM_READWRITE));
}

gst_sample_set_property()
{
  ...
  case PROP_TEST:
   sample->test = (TEST *) g_value_get_pointer(value);
   g_print("Struct filename:%s \t width:%u \t height:%u \n", 
        sample->test->filename,
        sample->test->width, 
        sample->test->height);
}

gst_sample_get_property()
{
  ...
  case PROP_TEST:
   g_value_set_pointer(value, sample->test);
   break;
}
```

Gstreamer application code :-

```
typedef struct _test
{
    gchar *filename;
    guint width;
    guint height;
}TEST;

main()
{
  ...
  TEST test, *test1;

  test.filename = "Structure";
  test.width = 14;
  test.height = 50;
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(sample), "test", &test, NULL);  
  ...
  g_object_get(G_OBJECT(sample), "test", &test1, NULL);
  g_print("Struct Addr:%p \t filename:%s \t width:%u \t height:%u \n",
           &test1, test1->filename, test1->width, test1->height); 
}
```